# Replace comma with decimal separator from TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Can someone tell me how can I replace a `,` separator with a `.` in my textfield? The user can input something like `5,6` but when he press a button I want to submit the data he has inputed as `5,6` to `5.6` because otherwise the decimal calculations are not made.

I have this extension string file but seems to work just for limitation of one comma in text and two decimal after the comma, not converting the `,` to `.`

```
extension String {

private static let decimalFormatter:NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.allowsFloats = true
    return formatter
}()

private var decimalSeparator:String{
    return String.decimalFormatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
}


func isValidDecimal(maximumFractionDigits:Int)->Bool{

    guard self.isEmpty == false else {
        return true
    }

    // Check if valid decimal
    if let _ = String.decimalFormatter.number(from: self){

        // Get fraction digits part using separator
        let numberComponents = self.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
        let fractionDigits = numberComponents.count == 2 ? numberComponents.last ?? "" : ""
        return fractionDigits.characters.count <= maximumFractionDigits
    }

    return false
}

var doubleValue: Double {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.decimalSeparator = "."
    if let result = nf.number(from: self) {
        return result.doubleValue
    } else {
        nf.decimalSeparator = ","
        if let result = nf.number(from: self) {
            return result.doubleValue
        }
    }
    return 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on button write below code for replace your string

```
let strReplace = txtField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".", options: .literal, range: nil)// change "txtField" your textfield's object
print(\(strReplace))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Delegate method for uitextfield

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

and then add the self in viewdidload

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And then add the below function inside of the function you able to change the characters

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) {

 print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
 let strReplace = txtField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".", options: .literal, range: nil)
// change "txtField" your textfield's object
 print(\(strReplace))

}
```

now you able to get the replacement string as well as whats the textfield text at present.!